# What are INC_OP, *_OP etc in the GLSL grammar specification?

Tags: parsing, glsl, context-free-grammar

I'm reading the [GLSL language grammar](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) and it has this section:

> The grammar is fed from the output of lexical analysis. The tokens returned from lexical analysis are
> ...
> LEFT_OP RIGHT_OP
> INC_OP DEC_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP

The rest of the language spec doesn't mention these tokens, at least not by the same name. My guess would be that LEFT_OP is `<<` and `INC_OP` is `+=` but I don't know how to verify this. Also if `INC_OP` is `+=` it's unclear if `NE_OP` would be `!=` since one is assignment and the other isn't.

Also is there a general way in a language spec to match these tokens to their definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no universal registry of token names, so the best you can do in cases like this is use your intuitions.

INC_OP and DEC_OP must be `++` and `--`, respectively, since `+=` and `-=` are ADD_ASSIGN and SUB_ASSIGN. (All the assignment operators appear to be of the form X_ASSIGN.)

It's certainly careless for the specification to not specify the token spellings.